# Flutter how to hide Cupertino bottom navigation bar at next page

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, cupertinonavigationbar

I currently working on a project need to build with Cupertino widget. Everything is fine until I trying not to display bottom navigation bar at next page, but the bottom navigation bar still bring forward from previous page. Below is my example code.

```dart
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person), label: 'Person'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.mail), label: 'Mail'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.flag), label: 'Flag'),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CupertinoTabView(
          routes: {
            'p2': (context) => PageTwo(),
          },
          builder: (context) {
            return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'p2');
                        },
                        child: Text('Next Page'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(children: [
          Text('Page 2'),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text('Back'),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you return page two in cupertinotabview user navigator.push command and wrap your pagetwo container with scaffold

Comment: @HamzaSiddiqui thank for reply.  It work after remove the CupertinoTabView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solutions.

##### First solution.

Just repace

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,'p2');
```

to

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed('p2');
```

##### Second solution

Remove the CupertinoTabView from tabBuilder if not necessary to use it

```dart
  tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CupertinoPageScaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'p2');
                  },
                  child: Text('Next Page'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
```

*imprtant: must set routes for class CupertinoApp*

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourScreen()));